# Bash Grep Numerical Constant in Row

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a tsv file and in column 22 I want to awk  all rows that do not have 100.0% as a numeric constant. All the other values would be 0.0%

I tried:

```
cat Product_Adaption.tsv | awk '$22 != /100.0%/' | cut -f1,22 | awk -F '\t' '{print $0, "Missing "}' | head
```

It still prints all the 100.0% values and not the 0.0% values

How to get grep only the rows in column 22 that have 0.0%

```
Column 1    Column 22 
26483335    0.00%
26483335    0.00%
6522321 100.00%
10058064    100.00%
26483335    0.00%
1061749 100.00%
26483335    100.00%
1098801 0.00%
83895846    0.00%
10058124    100.00%
26483335    0.00%
90872300    100.00%
9646863 100.00%
26483335    100.00%
26483335    0.00%
26483335    100.00%
```

When I use

```
cat Product_Adaption.tsv |awk '$22 != /^100\.0%$/'| cut -f1,22 | awk -F '\t' '{print $0, "Missing"}' | head
```

I get this as output

```
26483335        0.0% Missing
26483335        0.0% Missing
6522321 100.0% Missing
10058064        100.0% Missing
26483335        0.0% Missing
1061749 100.0% Missing
26483335        100.0% Missing
1098801 0.0% Missing
83895846        0.0% Missing
```

The regex doesn't seem to work?

Comment: post a sample, input file with you command.

Comment: Instead of getting non %100 values, you can get %0 values, if there are no values in between.

Comment: i think the problem is only because of `!=`

Comment: Although it doesn't look like it `'$22 != /100.0%/'` is two commands. It evaluates the `/100.0%/`(which is `$0~/100.0%/`) first then compares $22 to the value returned(either 1 or 0) which will never match a percentage and so will print every line.

Comment: thanks JID so do you know how to solbe this?

Comment: @Vic23 Avinash Raj's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you have so many commands and pipes and are mixing string operations with regexp delimiters, etc. It seems like all you'd need its:

```
awk -F'\t' '$22 == "0.00%"{print $1, $22, "Missing"}' Product_Adaption.tsv
```

Sometimes you show `0.00%` and others you show `0.0%` in your question so idk what your input file really contains but just use whichever is correct in the above script.

Comment: using your command line, if I were to awk grep to strings from column 22, say 0.00% and 50.00%, the logic would be to add in a pipe or dash but this doesn't seem to work. See below:                                             ------                                                                                                          awk -F'\t' '$22 == "0.00%|50.00%"{print $1, $22, "Missing"}' Product_Adaption.tsv                                                                                    Any suggestions on how to write this then?

Comment: You really need to get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins as you are misunderstanding some awk fundamental, e.g. the difference between strings and regular expressions.

Comment: `var=="str"` is a STRING comparison, not a regexp comparison. You can't put regexp operators like `|` inside a string and expect them to be treated as anything other than that literal character - that's the whole point of a string is that all characters are literal. It sounds like what you want is `$22 ~ /^(0|50).00%$/` - the `~` is a regexp operator and the `/`s are regexp delimiters, both of which are completely different from string operators like `==` and string delimiters `"`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to get grep only the rows in column 22 that have 0.0% ?

```
awk '$22 ~ /^0\.0%$/' file
```

OR

```
awk '$22 == "0.0%"' file
```

OR

```
awk '$22 !~ /^100\.0%$/' file
```

I think your regex won't work because of the comparision operator you used. Don't use `==` or `!=` for comparison when regex is used.

```
$ cat yi
0.0% bar
100.0% foo
$ awk '$1 ~ /^0\.0%$/' yi
0.0% bar
$ awk '$1 == "0.0%"' yi
0.0% bar
$ awk '$1 == /^0\.0%$/' yi
$ 
$ awk '$1 !~ /^100\.0%$/' yi
0.0% bar
```

Comment: is your column 22 contains only `100.0%`? or is there any some text exists like `foo100.0%` ? If the 22 col is like `foo100.0%` then remove the anchors from the above regex like `awk '$1 !~ /100\.0%/'`

Comment: it only contains either 100.0% or 0.0%

Answer (score 0):

```
Column 1    Column 22 
26483335    0.00%
26483335    0.00%
6522321 100.00%
10058064    100.00%
26483335    0.00%
1061749 100.00%
26483335    100.00%
1098801 0.00%
83895846    0.00%
10058124    100.00%
26483335    0.00%
90872300    100.00%
9646863 100.00%
26483335    100.00%
26483335    0.00%
26483335    100.00%
```

When I use

```
cat Product_Adaption.tsv |awk '$22 != /^100\.0%$/'| cut -f1,22 | awk -F '\t' '{print $0, "Missing"}' | head
```

I get this as output

```
26483335        0.0% Missing
26483335        0.0% Missing
6522321 100.0% Missing
10058064        100.0% Missing
26483335        0.0% Missing
1061749 100.0% Missing
26483335        100.0% Missing
1098801 0.0% Missing
83895846        0.0% Missing
```

The regex doesn't seem to work?

Comment: i suggest you to use `awk '$22 !~ /^100\.0%$/' Product_Adaption.tsv` , not `!=` ,it's `!~` . And also you don't need to use cat command.